# Getting Error in Yii2 as PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library apc.so

Tags: php, yii2, apc, yii2-advanced-app

I am Getting this below Error in Yii2 advanced template

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library `'/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/apc.so'` - `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/apc.so`: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can i fix this Error?

Comment: AFAIK APC is only loaded if the cache component is set to `ApcCache`. Did you happen to change the configuration? (By default it is set to use `FileCache`)

Comment: so what i wanna do now

Comment: Well check your configuration files (in the `config/` folders either below `common/` and `frontend/`) if the `ApcCache` is being used. If so you can either use another caching method or install the apc-module on your server if that is a possibility.

Comment: ApcCache is not used in my config, what i wanna do now

Comment: Look... I'm a lot of things but I'm not clairvoyant. 
If it's not Yii via the cache component then you are trying to use apc-functions (`apc_add`, `apc_fetch`, ...) somewhere else. You'll have to find out where. There's not a lot more we can do with the info you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your live server php version into php 5.5, thats it.